# Finger print reader does nothing on login

Tags: fingerprint

**Fingerprint reader:** Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint

**OS:** POP!_OS 20.04 LTS

**System:** Dell XPS 9500

**Description:**
I have followed this post to install fingerprint drivers on my laptop: [XPS 13 9300 - Does fingerprint reader work on Linux?](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9300-Does-fingerprint-reader-work-on-linux/m-p/7628310/highlight/true#M63982). After completing installation, I was able to add my fingerprints via the settings/users menu. However, when trying to unlock the computer with fingerprint, nothing happens, there is just a small message under the login box saying "(or swipe finger)".

Please let me know if there is any further information needed :) thank you in advance